# Ask about the symbol meaning of regular expression (redis)

Tags: regex, redis, lua

I execute lua script in redis

This is what I see from the internet

Create a JSON file first:
`set obj'{"a":"foo","b":"bar"}'`

Change b:bar to b:bar2:
`EVAL'local obj = redis.call("get",KEYS[1]); local obj2 = string.gsub(obj,"(" .. ARGV[1] .. "\":)([^,}] +)", "%1" .. ARGV[2]); return redis.call("set",KEYS[1],obj2);' 1 obj b bar2`

Finally, the query results:
`get obj`

Will get the result:
**"{"a":"foo","b":bar2}"**

I want to ask about the purpose of some symbols:

1. Ask what is the purpose of `..` ? (The difference between `.. ARGV[1] ..` and `.. ARGV[2]` ?
2. Ask what is the purpose of `"\":` ?(Am I wrong, is it `"\":` or `.. "\":` together?)
3. Ask what is the purpose of `[^,}]+` ?

Comment: 1. and 2. have nothing to do with a _regular expression_. 3. means one or more of `^`, `,` or `}`.

Comment: `..` is operator of string concatenation, `\"` is escaped quote inside quoted string literal,  `[^,}]` is regex for any symbol except comma and closing curly brace